# Replace elements value of table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there was a billion questions like my but I still can't find solution, and I know it's basic and fundamentals of JS but I'm new with this language.

Ok, so I have table

```
<table>
    <tr id = 'first'>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>SomeName</td>
        <td>
             <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, -1);">Up</a>
             <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, 1);">Down</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>SomeName2</td>
        <td>
             <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, -1);">Up</a>
             <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, 1);">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I need to make functionality which allows to replacing table rows under `<th>#` . When I put row with *#2* on place *#1* I want to keep proper orders of rows, *1,2* etc. I have row *2* on first place in my table but with *#2*, I need to change it.

It looks like this:

```
    function moveChoiceTo(elem_choice, direction) {
        var tr = elem_choice.parentNode.parentNode,
        td = tr.parentNode;

        if (direction === -1 && tr.previousElementSibling && 
          !tr.previousElementSibling.id) {
            td.insertBefore(tr, tr.previousElementSibling);
        } else if (direction === 1 && tr.nextElementSibling) {
            td.insertBefore(tr, tr.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling)
        }
    }
```

But I still have no idea how to make my *#* unchanged. I want to use for it JQ but I've tried different solutions and none of them works.

I've tried

```
$(tr.firstElementChild.innerHTML).before($(tr.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.innerHTML));

 $(tr.firstElementChild.innerHTML).html(tr.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.innerHTML);

$(tr.firstElementChild.innerHTML).replaceWith($(tr.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.innerHTML));
```

And some others combination but i can't figured out what is wrong. Do I pass JS variable to JQ function in wrong way?

My table should looks like:

```
<table>
    <tr id = 'first'>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>SomeName2</td>
        <td>
             <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, -1);">Up</a>
             <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, 1);">Down</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>SomeName1</td>
        <td>
             <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, -1);">Up</a>
             <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, 1);">Down</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Name, action and others rows replaced places but #id is unchanged

EDIT.

Ok, I'm the stupidest man on the earth.

This is solution I was looking for:

```
$(tr.firstElementChild).html(tr.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild.innerHTML++);
```

when I go up, and

```
$(tr.firstElementChild).html(tr.nextElementSibling.firstElementChild.innerHTML--);
```

when I go down

Comment: with what you want to replace the table rows?

Comment: @randomSoul I have edited my post, I need to leave my id's under <th> #</th> unchanged

Comment: Can you please add up the table structure you want as an output?

Comment: @randomSould I've added my table with resoult I want to achive

Comment: You want to swap rows?

Comment: @connexo Exactly!

Comment: See my answer (which works even for dynamically inserted rows).

Answer (score 1):

Get second tr using `$('tr').eq(1)`, then get all the children of tr and then use eq(1) to get second td.

```js
const td1 = $('tr').eq(1).children().eq(1);
const td2 = $('tr').eq(2).children().eq(1);

const temp = td1.text();

td1.text(td2.text());
td2.text(temp);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id='first'>
    <th>#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>SomeName</td>
    <td>
      <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, -1);">Up</a>
      <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, 1);">Down</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>SomeName2</td>
    <td>
      <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, -1);">Up</a>
      <a href="" onclick="return moveChoiceTo(this, 1);">Down</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution using a delegate listener on the `table` element:

```js
myTable.addEventListener('click', function({
  target: t
}) {
  if (t.tagName === 'BUTTON' && ['up', 'down'].includes(t.textContent.toLowerCase())) {
    let row = t.closest('tr');
    switch (t.textContent.toLowerCase()) {
      case 'up':
        let prevRow = row.previousElementSibling;
        if (prevRow) {
          row.parentElement.insertBefore(row, prevRow);
        }
        break;
      case 'down':
        let nextRow = row.nextElementSibling;
        if (nextRow) {
          row.parentElement.insertBefore(nextRow, row);
        }
        break;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr id="first">
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>SomeName1</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button">Up</button>
        <button type="button">Down</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>SomeName2</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button">Up</button>
        <button type="button">Down</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>SomeName3</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button">Up</button>
        <button type="button">Down</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>SomeName4</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button">Up</button>
        <button type="button">Down</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>SomeName5</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button">Up</button>
        <button type="button">Down</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>SomeName6</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button">Up</button>
        <button type="button">Down</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```